# How to rename file in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

In Spring Tool Suite, I have a project open and want to rename a .java file. I click the file then File > Rename and rename the file. I see the file name updates in the left pane (Project Explorer) but then it quickly changes back to the old file name.

Any one know how to accomplish this or what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided answers would probably work in most cases but not for me. I had to rename the file on disk, refresh the Project Explorer, which picked up the new name. The go back on disk and rename the file to the target name, refresh PE and now all is well.

Comment: if you rename the file the recommended way, is there any related error showing up in the Error Log view?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're running into but the following works for me.

Step 1.

[image: Step 1.]

Step 2.

[image: Step 2.]

Step 3.

[image: Step 3.]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to rename a class in eclipse:

1. Mark the class in the project explorer
2. Press F2
3. Rename as you like in the dialog box
4. OK

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use:

```
1. Refactor
2. Rename
```

And also make sure that you change the class name

Comment: That's the same as File > Rename. It also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Open the class file you want to rename.  In the text editor, double-click on the class name to select it.  Now do Alt-Shift-R (or right-click on selected text and select Refactor>Rename in the context menu) and rename the class, then click Enter/Return.  The STS Refactor/Renaming wizard should take over and rename both the class and the file from there.

Comment: This doesn't rename the file and that create an error because the class needs to be in a file of the same name.

Comment: Actually, I can see the file on disk has been renamed but the Project Explorer is still showing the old name.

Comment: How to again rename the file on disk, refresh the Project Explorer, which picked up the new name. The go back on disk rename, refresh PE and now all is well.

Comment: Yep - I've also seen that the Project Explorer view doesn't always update itself appropriately.  But I've never experienced a case where a quick "Clean" and "Refresh" didn't fix the display issue.